# Python Exception handling 3 input floats

Tags: python, exception

I'm learning about exception handling in Python. I have written this simple code below. If I enter a invalid value for the first number it  will print out "One of your inputs are wrong!" and won't let me enter in values for num2 or num3
I want to change the code so if I enter an invalid value for the first number,it will still ask me to enter in values for num2 and num3 and then if any of the values are invalid  it will print "One of your inputs are wrong"
Can someone please help me with this, I would be so grateful, thanks.

```
  def main():
    try:
        num1 = int(input("Enter in Number 1: ")) # ask the user for num1
        
        num2 = int(input("Enter in Number 2: ")) # ask the user for num2

        num3 = int(input("Enter in Number 3: ")) # ask the user for num3

    except ValueError:
     # only run this code if any of the three numbers are invalid 

        print("One of your inputs are wrong!") 
    else:
        print("The answer is ", num1 + num2 + num3)  
main()
```

Answer (score -1):

`try-except` blocks are like `if-else` blocks and hence you can nest them.

You can try this:

```
def main():
    try:
        num1 = int(input("Enter in Number 1: ")) # ask the user for num1     
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter num2 and num3") 
        try:
            num2 = int(input("Enter in Number 2: ")) # ask the user for num2
            num3 = int(input("Enter in Number 3: ")) # ask the user for num3
        except ValueError:
            print("One of your inputs are wrong!")
        else:
            print("The answer is ", num1 + num2 + num3) 
    finally:
        print("this block ends here!")
     
main()
```